# Enhanced iOS barcode scanner library?

Tags: iphone, ios, barcode, barcode-scanner

We're creating an iOS app that basically scans badges at events and collects contact info.  We're looking for an iOS library that can read not only the number of the barcode, but also any additional information that's included (contact info).  Does anyone have any library suggestions or will this have to be a custom library?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What barcode types are on badges?

Answer (score 19):

**Updated:**

Use AVCaptureMetaDataOutput in AVFoundation which works with minimum deployment target iOS 7.

**Previous Answer:**

Have been using [ZBar SDK](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/) in most of our projects. Picks up barcode and scans very fast, easy to customize focus area from SDK. Tested on iPhone 3GS, iPhone4/4S, iPhone 5 and iPad

Answer (score 4):

https://codeload.github.com/cgreening/BarCodeExample/zip/master

iOS7 has built in functionality scanning BarCodes not sepearate sdk is required; if your deployment target is iOS7

Answer (score 2):

Is your barcode format up to you, or do you have a predetermined symbology you have to work with?

There is this: http://shopsavvy.mobi/sdk/.  Don't know why that wouldn't work for you, unless you object to the licensing terms.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout ZXing ("Zebra Crossing") at http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Reads almost every kind of barcodes and we used it with great success previously.

Comment: Some modules are contributed and/or intermittently maintained: iphone: iPhone client + port to Objective C / C++ (QR code only). Doesn't sound terribly useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use ZBAR its the best, we used it in our app [www.infomq.com](http://www.infomq.com) and its is really stable and scans reliably.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you want to use [PDF417](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417) which is a stacked linear barcode symbol.  Check out the [pdf417 decode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf417decode/) on Sourceforge.

Comment: do anyone know how to use this ?

Comment: This is extremely impractical to implement on iOS at the moment.  A much better alternative is QR Codes.