# Barcode SDK to support 1D, QR code, data matrix etc. for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, barcode, barcode-scanner

I need a bar code engine to support above 3 bar code types (1D, QR code, data matrix) for iPhone. I tried zxing, zbar which in my case doesnt support data matrix. I found some commercial versions also.

But I am looking for a free SDK.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569867/enhanced-ios-barcode-scanner-library/5570209#5570209

Comment: possible duplicate of [barcode framework for the iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/barcode-framework-for-the-iphone)

Comment: Thanks Till and Brad. Yes there are many and what I want to find is a bar code reader which supports 1D, QR code, data matrix and also it should be free. Currently I could not find any :(

Comment: one type I am not finding is pdf417.

Comment: AFAIK, zxing supports QR, data matrix and 1D. You just need to include the decoders you want the images to go through.

Comment: @harshalb we also didn't find proper PDF417 scanner SDK, so we developed our own. More info on http://pdf417.mobi

Comment: @ssasa This is a very old thread. Now you can find many alternatives for this.

Answer (score 2):

This question is very old, but I'd like to answer it anyway for completeness. I would recommend [zxing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/), as it supports all the codes mentioned in the question.

However, since iOS7 there is also the option of using the [built-in scanner API](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (which I have found quicker and more accurate than zxing after a couple of hours testing). I also found the Cocoa APIs slightly easier to integrate with a custom UI. The downside is that (to my knowledge) Data Matrix is not supported.

A third option would be to use a clever combination of both, maybe also to fall back gracefully for pre-iOS7 devices.

Comment: Well, fair enough. I actually used Xamarin when testing this anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes zxing had that support now. Back in the day there was no proper barcode reader to read all type of barcodes. I believe now they have improved a lot and they support most of the barcodes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no free SDK for1D, QR code, data matrix for Iphone. zbar is not supporting , ive tried zxing its working ,but allot of background work have to be done with zxing sdk.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 8, Data Matrix is supported in AVFoundation. see:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Machine_Readable_Object_Types